# White shades in PNG image in JOGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

I am working with OpenGL binding for JAVA(jogl) and I am trying to load a png image in a circle that I have created with Photoshop. That works fine, but the problem is when I am rendering it a white shade displays in the circle. Can anyone help me why this is because?

My code is here,

```
private static void drawCircleUsingPoly(float x, float y, float r, GL2 gl,String fileName){
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"assets"+ File.separator + fileName);
    try {
        textureId = TextureIO.newTexture(file, true).getTextureObject(gl);
    } catch (GLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
    for (float angle=0.0f; angle<360.0; angle+=2.0){
        float radian = angle * (3.1415926f/180.f);
        float xcos = (float)Math.cos(radian);
        float ysin = (float)Math.sin(radian);

        float vx = xcos * r + x;
        float vy = ysin * r + y;

        float tx = xcos * 0.5f + 0.5f;
        float ty = ysin * 0.5f + 0.5f;
        gl.glTexCoord2f(tx, ty);
        gl.glVertex2f(vx, vy);

    }
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_ONE, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL2.GL_MODULATE);
    gl.glDepthMask(true);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glEnd();
}
```

[screen shot attaching here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrjev.png)

Comment: Looks to me as if the overlay images doesn't fit your circle. Does this also happen when you combine the two images in photoshop?

Comment: No. It is works fine when i am added an image that is downloaded from google

Comment: Have you tried calling `gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND)`  at the beginning of your method?